# Traversing the DOM, DomNodeList using php

Tags: php, dom, traversal

I would like to ask why query "teams" node can give me some results (count = 1, length = 1) but not "root" or "subteam". All the nodes "root, teams and subteam" are Nodelist type.

If I am not mistaken,  the count 1 represents the number of node in the list.. so why "root" and "subteam" returns 0.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<root> 
<teams>
<subteams>
    <cmd>login</cmd> 
    <login>Richard</login> 
</subteams>
</teams>

</root> 
XML;


$dom->loadXML($string);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
/*DOMNodeList*/
$queryNode = $xpath->query("subteams"); //length 0, count 0
//$queryNode = $xpath->query("root"); //length 0, count 0
//$queryNode = $xpath->query("teams"); //length 1, count 1

echo "length " . $queryNode->length . "<br>";
echo "count " . $queryNode->count() . "<br>";
var_dump( $queryNode); // only for teams node - object(DOMNodeList)#4 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) }
```

Thanks

[image: Please see DOM picture]

Comment: Thank you very much Phill. That explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expressions are missing path separators.

For example, if you want all `subteams` anywhere in the document, use

```
$queryNode = $xpath->query("//subteams");
```

You could also use

```
$queryNode = $xpath->query("/root/team/subteams");
```

or

```
$queryNode = $xpath->query("team/subteams");
```

---

`"team"` works because the default context of your queries is the document element, ie `<root>`.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-path-expressions